# Who are you and what are you?

Tags: knowledge, rebus, emoji

The answer is 11 letters.

> 1. **VERT** VERT VERT
> 2. VERT VERT VERT **VERT** (theres supposed to be three here)
> 3. What is in **Tuit**ion 5-6ABC?
> 4. Segnse
> 5. Gkthkg
> 6. Gfeelg
> 7. G‍⚖️g
> 8. G%g

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are:.

> Personality types! (Preferences).

VERT VERT VERT.

> Intro-vert.

VERT VERT VERT VERT (theres supposed to be three here)

> Extravert.

What is in Tuition 5-6ABC?

> Intuition.

Segnse.

> Sensing (sense, in g?).

Gkthkg.

> Thinking (th in k in g).

Gfeelg.

> Feeling (feel in g).

G‍⚖️g.

> Judging (judge in g).

G%g.

> Perceiving (per sneeze in g).

Which are you?!

Comment: Thats close enough.